# Check if an array contains a specific object only once

Tags: karate

Given the following input:

```
* def response = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
* def item = { a: 1 }
```

How to check that `item` is present only once in `response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, since less common. You can do this in 2 steps by filtering the list and then using `contains only`.

```
* def response = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]
* def item = { a: 1 }
* match response contains item

* def fun = function(x){ return karate.match(x, item).pass }
* def filt = karate.filter(response, fun)
* match filt contains only item
```

Comment: This does not work for me, since I want to check for a match on partial object. Please see my edit.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough, but there is no need to open a new question, because this is the problem that I want to solve with the current question. From the docs: "A very useful capability is to be able to check that an array contains an object that contains the provided sub-set of keys instead of having to specify the complete JSON". This is why I use `match list contains '#(^msg)'`. But also I would like to check that there is only one partial match from the whole list. If I still didn't make myself clear enough, we could continue in chat.

Comment: @helleye yes your question was not clear enough, and IMO your edit fundamentally changed the question. just open a new question, it will take you a second ^_^

Comment: I've updated the question to comply with your answer and now everything looks ok.